# How to put 2 div in one line

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs. The first div contains a large sentence. And in the end of this sentence I want to put a word, that is situated in the second div.
But I always get the next line. Here is my example

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="content1">Test and share JavaScript, CSS, HTML or CoffeeScript online.. JsFiddle is the playground for web developers, an online editor for web </div>
        <div class="content2">snippets</div>
</div>
```

[image]

And I want to get this

[image]

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4utsx65f/1/)

Comment: add `display: inline;` for css classes

Comment: If you only have textual data in your `div`, why don't you use then `label`, or `span` - which are by default `inline`?

Comment: Here is just an example. I need only divs, I use GWT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change `display` from `inline-block` to `inline`.

```
.content1, .content2 {
    display: inline;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4utsx65f/2/

Answer (score 4):

Please do not use div's for content. Change the parent Container to a p-tag (`<p>`) and the following divs (in this case `<div class="content1">` and `<div class="content2">`) to span-tags (). Their are by default `display:inline;`.

If it's just content-text without special styling, remove any tags and let it inside the parent p-tag.

I would recommend using the following code:

```
<p class="container">
        Test and share JavaScript, CSS, HTML or CoffeeScript online.. JsFiddle is the playground for web developers, an online editor for web <span class="content2">snippets</span>
</p>
```

Based on your Screenshots, this would fit as a more appropriate solution. Hower as the other Suggested already, you cann still change the CSS if you cannot change the HTML for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Div is by default a block element. If you want inline elements you should (in theory) use spans.

For example:

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="content1">Test and share JavaScript, CSS, HTML or CoffeeScript online.. JsFiddle is the playground for web developers, an online editor for web </span >
    <span class="content2">snippets</span >
</div>
```

Now, if you cannot change that for some reasons you probably will have to change that specific div's css 'display' property to 'inline', though I'd actually recommend against it.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
.container div{
     display:inline;
 }
```

Or use inline elements, like spans instead of divs

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline` for your inner divs: http://jsfiddle.net/4utsx65f/3/

Answer (score 1):

I Guess the second word snippet should be in span as per the requirement.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content1">Test and share JavaScript, CSS, HTML or CoffeeScript online.. JsFiddle is the playground for web developers, an online editor for web
```

snippets

check this fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4utsx65f/5/)

Answer (score 1):

make a Css file in your Assets ..
define a class with any name .withen the defination write.

```
    .divOnSameLine{
             display:inline;
             float:left;
     }
```

make sure to refer the css file in your Document.
then add the class name

```
<div class="divleft divOnSameLine">Something</div>
<div class="divright divOnSameLine">Something 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'display: inline-block;' to the content1 and content2 classes in your CSS, or set the value inline:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content1" style="display:inline-block;'>Test and share JavaScript, CSS, HTML or CoffeeScript online.. JsFiddle is the playground for web developers, an online editor for web </div>
    <div class="content2" style="display:inline-block;'>snippets</div>
```